# Naming cookies in ASP.NET 5

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core

In my ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 app, I'm using ONLY the cookie middleware without ASP.NET Identity -- as described in this document: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/cookie.html

I'm also using social authentication i.e. Facebook, Google, etc. So the user authenticates through the social network, then I use the cookie middleware to manage user's session.

In the app, I need to create two cookies i.e. a temp cookie before a new user completes registration and a regular cookie once the registration is completed.

I want to name these cookies and be able to look for them by their names. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the default cookie name directly in the middleware options:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(options => {
    options.AuthenticationScheme = "Instance1";
    options.CookieName = "MyCookie";
});

app.UseCookieAuthentication(options => {
    options.AuthenticationScheme = "Instance2";
    options.CookieName = "MyOtherCookie";
});
```

To retrieve the `ClaimsPrincipal` instance associated with a particular scheme, use `AuthenticateAsync`:

```
var principal = await context.Authentication.AuthenticateAsync("Instance2");
```

Comment: And how do I look for a particular cookie, say, MyOtherCookie? Currently, I just get the user as var user = HttpContext.User. How would I specifically get user information from "MyOtherCookie". This is important for me because if the "MyOtherCookie" doesn't exist, I need to redirect the user to sign up page, etc.

Comment: You need to use `AuthenticateAsync` for that.

Comment: I see. Maybe implement an AuthorizeFilter so that I can intercept the request before it reaches the controller method and check for the cookie type, correct?

Comment: You could decorate your actions with `[Authorize(ActiveAuthenticationSchemes = "MyOtherCookie")]`, but using `AuthenticateAsync` might be more appropriate if you need to control precisely where the user should be redirected per-action or per-controller instead of globally (that's what `SignInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync` does).